# Connection String to Local DB file is not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, connection-string, aspnetdb

```
connectionString="AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\nmartin\My Documents\PS_Upload\TimeTrack\src\TimeTracker\TimeTrack\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the connection string that is provided to me from the Server Explorer for my local MDF file. I keep receiving the following error when attempting to run the application.

```
"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 25."
```

Anyone know what this is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it is the spaces in file name. Try enclosing it in '' e.g.

```
connectionString="AttachDbFilename='C:\Documents and Settings\nmartin\My Documents\PS_Upload\TimeTrack\src\TimeTracker\TimeTrack\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True"
```

or copy it to c:\ for a test

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot everyone. My problem was actually with the connection string I was providing NHibernate configuration. It would appear that the local data file path should not be wrapped in 's or "s. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Thanks, single quotes (') was my problem too.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:  Integrated Security=True

With: Trusted_Connection=Yes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using escape characters on the backslashes?

```
connectionString="AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\nmartin\My Documents\PS_Upload\TimeTrack\src\TimeTracker\TimeTrack\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

becomes

```
connectionString="AttachDbFilename=C:\\Documents and Settings\\nmartin\\My Documents\\PS_Upload\\TimeTrack\\src\\TimeTracker\\TimeTrack\\App_Data\\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```